# Is there any workaround to send Facebook Graph api Game Request without Facebook dialog?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, mobile-application

In our mobile game we have list of Facebook friends who already play it or are invitable_friends. Invitable friends have invite buttons next to them.

After pressing invite button Facebook invite dialog is showing up. This adds additional clicks for users and might disturb them.

Is there any workaround to send Game Request to selected users without Facebook dialog?

P.S. I have read about FBFrictionlessRecipientCache, but as I understand, it works only if a user clicks its selector checkbook on invite dialog. This isn't solution for us.

Comment: You can specify the recipients beforehand using the `to` parameter of the dialog, but that’s it – the user will still have to confirm the request by submitting the dialog.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Sadly, that's true :/ and that is the reason why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Yeah that's by design to not send requests without dialog unless they have selected the frictionless option.